# Algorithm to distribute a jackpot between winners

Tags: algorithm

I'm building a betting pool system and I have to split the jackpot between all participants given the number of hits (accurate predictions of a certain sport game) they achieved, where more hits means a bigger prize.

For example, if we want to distribute a 1000 coins jackpot for this betting pool, we could use this distribution:

[image: example]

Is there any algorithm to calculate the prize given to each winner given this conditions?

Comment: Without more information we can only guess. Where is the distribution coming from? A real lottery? If yes there is always documentation how the money gets distributed between the winners.

Comment: No, it's a fantasy game, the distribution is defined by us and it's what we are trying to define honoring the conditions explained.

Comment: You haven't explained all of the conditions.  All you've said is that more hits means a bigger prize, but you haven't given any guidance on how you determine how much bigger that prize should be.  In your posted example, getting a 4th hit triples your prize from 4 to 12; getting a 5th hit only doubles it.  Neither the proportion nor the absolute margin follow any established payout scheme.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing how you want to split the prize, one option is to calculate the total number of hits by all users, and divide the jackpot by that number to find the prize awarded to each hit.

You can then just go through and give each user a prize that is this number multiplied by the number of hits.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define how big the share for which number of hits is

```
Hits, winWeight, numberOfWinners
5,    24,        n(5)
4,    12,        n(4)
3,     4,        n(3)
2,     2,        n(2)
1,     1,        n(1)
```

than you multiply these values with number of winners and get:

```
total=24*n(5)+12*n(4)+4*n(3)+2*n(2)+1*n(1)
```

Now you calculate how many coins:

```
jackpot/total * 24  = pricePerWinner for 5 hits
jackpot/total * 12  = pricePerWinner for 4 hits
jackpot/total *  4  = pricePerWinner for 3 hits
jackpot/total *  2  = pricePerWinner for 2 hits
jackpot/total *  1  = pricePerWinner for 1 hit
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the amount of total hits.

```
5*6 = 30
4*40 = 160
3*80 = 240
2*20 = 40
1*15 = 15
0*2 = 0
```

If you add them all up together it would total up to

```
30+160+240+40+15+0=485
```

Since there are 1000 coins for the jackpot.

```
1000/485 ~= 2
```

This means that for each hit, it would grant 2 coins.

Eg. 5 hits would mean 10 coins per winner